# How to resolve error ReferenceError: json_decode is not defined in nodejs coffeescript

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I want to retrieve facebook likes of my post.I have written the code but it display error.

```
    facebookDataUrl = "http://graph.facebook.com/yourstory.com/2016/04/shotpitch-startup-trended-product-hunt/"
    console.log facebookDataUrl     
    data = Http::curl(facebookDataUrl)
fbshares = json_decode(data, true)
fbsharescnt = fbshares['shares']
console.log fbsharescnt
```

Above code display the error

```
fbshares = json_decode(data, true);
         ^
```

ReferenceError: json_decode is not defined

Comment: `json_decode` is a PHP function.

Comment: Hi Felix Kling Could u tell me how can i do it in nodejs coffeescript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse()`.

```
get = require 'http-get-shim'                                            

url = 'http://graph.facebook.com/yourstory.com/2016/04/shotpitch-startup-trended-product-hunt/'                                                   

get url, (er, resp, body) ->                                             
  data = JSON.parse body                                                 
  console.log data
```

Comment: now it gives error ReferenceError: Http is not defined.please help me

Comment: You will need to take the time to learn the differences between PHP and JavaScript/CoffeeScript/Node.js.  It will take some time unfortunately.

Comment: It give Error: Cannot find module 'http-get-shim'

Comment: You will need to learn how node and npm work.  `npm i http-get-shim`

Comment: Thank you Jason Livesay.It works for me.Thanks for help.Right solution given by you.